# What are the benefits of storing a Firebase listener in a property SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I was wondering what the benefits of storing a Firebase listener, such as the `AuthStateDidChangeListener` or a Document Snapshot Listener in a property would be.

For example:

```
final class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var currentUser: User?
    
    private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    private var listener: ListenerRegistration?

    func listen() {
        guard handle == nil else { return }
        // This code will work irrespective of whether I put "handle =" or not
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, _ in
            if let user = auth.currentUser {
                self.currentUser = user
            } else {
                self.currentUser = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I hadn't stored the Auth State Change Listener in the `handle` property what would the consequences be? From what I can tell the code works the same. Similarly, for a Document Snapshot Listener, what are the differences whether I store the listener in a property:

```
listener = db.collection("col1").document("doc1").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in 
  \\...
}
```

vs. not storing it and simply having:

```
db.collection("col1").document("doc1").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in 
  \\...
}
```

**In summary:**
What are the differences between storing an `AuthStateDidChangeListener` or a Document Snapshot Listener in a property such as `handle` or `listener` vs. not storing it at all? What are the consequences of not storing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the method `addSomeListner() -> Listner` you are creating a special object, a `Listner`, that lets you perform an action when an event occurs.

Once created the `Listner` will start to listen for incoming events regardless of the state of your listened "data" or your context in where it's used.

What does it mean? and what are the implications?

### Example

You have a document that once is deleted it can not be recreated with the same ID.

Imagine a page where you display the data of a document named "DOCUMENT_UNIQUE_A". So you'll create a listener like this:

```swift
let myListner = document("DOCUMENT_UNIQUE_A").addSnapShotListner(\**/)
```

At some point, someone or the user will delete the document. When this happens your listener will receive the event of "document-deleted" and you'll perform some action (like updating your UI by deleting the document from a list or something else).

Now the important part. In the beginning, I said a `Listener` is an object that is constantly waiting for events. But in our case, this listener will never receive new events since we will never have a document with that same id.

By storing the listener you have the opportunity to remove it and free its memory space.

```swift
myListner.remove()
```

So to come to your questions.

1. **Why both codes work?** Because Firebase creates a strong reference to your listener that avoid the object to be automatically deallocated.
2. **What's the difference?** By storing the listener you are in control of it and you can remove it when you'll consider is the right time to do it.

### Examples of when a Listener should be removed

1. After a view is dismissed and its content depends on that listener.
2. If you are in a List and every row has a Listener, you should consider stop them when the Row is not displayed.
3. If you have a listener that is dependants on another listener.

### What about AuthListner?

The auth state listener is a special case since in your app session life you can always expecting user events (login-logout-invalidation) so it's often a good practice to never remove it or store it.

But be aware that, since at the end is a normal `Listener`, the exact same rules are applied to it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such an amazing reply. I still had a few questions regarding how firebase creates a strong reference to the object. Suppose I called `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { doc, err in //... }` multiple times in a row (without storing it), will this create multiple listeners? Also does quitting the app (swiping up on it from the multitasking UI) deallocate all listeners created without storing them in a property? Or does it pile up?

Comment: I did some experimenting on my own and this is what I found: Quitting the app deallocates all listeners (because if I relaunch the app, updates to the database don't trigger UI changes). Calling `addSnapshotListener` multiple times DOES in fact create multiple listeners (however all get deactivated when you quit the app). Have I missed any subtleties?

Comment: Thanks, @rayaantaneja. When you say "quitting the app" you mean force closing/killing the app in the apps manager? or you mean when the app goes in the background?

In any case, I would suggest putting some prints inside your listeners to see what is going on. And you should definitely have a look at how Swift manages references: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

And how references are managed in a closure scope. This will definitely help you understand the underline "problem".